# How to paint a window in my house yellow? [image processing with Mathematica]

Tags: image-processing

I first cut out the window from the image of the house, paint it yellow, and then overlay it on the image of the house.

I have **two questions**:

(1) Why did the yellow window and the house get **misaligned** when I added them together?

(2) Is there a way to change the color of the window directly in the image of the house **without cutting it out**?
Maybe I can use Image Mask to do this?

Thank you.

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
rTop = 169; yTop = 135.622;
rBot = 121; yBot = 87.027;
cLef = 106; xLef = 140.4;
cRig = 141; xRig = 105.6;
iwin = ImageTake[img, {rBot, rTop}, {cLef, cRig}];
iwiny = ImageRecolor[iwin, ColorsNear[White, 0.2] -> Yellow]
ImageAdd[img, iwiny]
```

[image: result of my code]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ImageCompose` with position instead of `ImageAdd`.

```
ImageCompose[img, iwiny, {rBot, cLef}]
```

---

[image]